# a function takes a predicate and a list return a tuple

Tags: python, recursion

```
def separate(p : callable, l : [object]) -> ([object],[object]):
    z = []
    d = []
    for item in l:
        if p(item):
            z  + [item]
            new_l = l.pop(item)
            separate(p,new_l)
        else:
            d + [item]
            new_l = l.pop(item)
            separate(p,new_l)
    h = tuple((z,d))
    return h
```

the function passed a predicate and a list; it returns a 2-tuple whose 0 index is a list of all the values in the argument list for which the predicate returns True, and whose 1 index is a list of all the values in the argument list for which the predicate returns False. You can use + to concatenate lists, but cannot mutate any list (e.g., no calls to append).

Calling separate((lambda x:x>=0),[1,-3,-2,4,0,-1,8])  returns

```
([1,4,0,8],[-3,-2,-1]).
```

But I am not sure why my function gives me an error that

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

the error I got is listed below:

```
*Error: s = separate(predicate.is_positive,[1, -3, -2, 4, 0, -1, 8]) raised exception TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

can someone tell me how to fix it? many thanks.

Comment: I only see one iteration, on `l`, so it seems that you're passing in an integer instead of an iterable for that argument. Also, the lines `z + [item]` and `d + [item]` aren't doing what you think they're doing.

Comment: I am not sure how to change it.

Comment: @zeyuxie **Do not vandalize your own posts here!** If you think it's not worth staying at the site simply delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't seem to have decided if it's solving this recursively or iteratively -- it has bits of both.  Assuming you introduced recursion intentionally, let's rethink and simplify the solution:

```
def separate(predicate: callable, array: [object]) -> ([object], [object]):
    positive, negative = list(), list()

    if array:
        if predicate(array[0]):
            positive.append(array[0])
        else:
            negative.append(array[0])

        p, n = separate(predicate, array[1:])

        positive += p
        negative += n

    return positive, negative
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
> python3 -i test.py
>>> separate((lambda x: x >= 0), [1, -3, -2, 4, 0, -1, 8])
([1, 4, 0, 8], [-3, -2, -1])
>>>  separate((lambda x: x % 2 == 0), [1, -3, -2, 4, 0, -1, 8])
([-2, 4, 0, 8], [1, -3, -1])
>>>
```